# Derivative of dot-product involving a matrix function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I am struggling with the following derivative
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{c}))$$
with $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{c}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ constants, and $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ function of $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^l$.
I know that
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{M}$$
with $\mathbf{M}$ a $3$D tensor, such that
$$M_{n,m,l}=\frac{\partial A_{n,m}}{\partial x_l}$$
but I am not able to find the results of the original problem starting from this result. I am primarly having trouble in retrieving the correct dimensions. Can you give me a hint?
Thanks

Comment: The gradient can be written using the double-dot product as
$\;g=(bc^T\!:{\mathbb M})\;$ or in index notation as
$$g_k = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m\;b_ic_j\:{\mathbb M}_{ijk}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{c}))$$
> with $\mathbf{b}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{c}\in \mathbb{R}^m$ constants, and $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ function of $\mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^l$.

$$\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{c})=\sum_{i,j}b_i A_{ij}c_j$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}[\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{c})]=\sum_{i,j}b_i \frac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial x_k}c_j=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mb_i~ M_{ijk}~c_{j}~~~~~~~~k=1,2,...,l$$

In vector form:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial \mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\,\mathbf{c}))=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mb_i~ M_{ij1}~c_{j},~~\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mb_i~ M_{ij2}~c_{j},~~...,\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^mb_i~ M_{ijl}~c_{j}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

As has been demonstrated by others, the derivative you are looking for is
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{c})\right) = \mathbf{c}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{M}), $$
where
$\mathbf{M} = \nabla \mathbf{A}$ is defined as in the OP, and I follow the convention that dot products on the left (resp. right) of $\mathbf{M}$ operate over the index in its first (resp. last) position.

Here I give a coordinate-free calculation based on differential forms which I find cleaner than using tensor indices (although it is useful to be able to handle such calculations in both ways).  Indeed, we have
$$ d\left(\mathbf{b}\cdot(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{c})\right) = \mathbf{b}\cdot (d\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{c}) = \mathbf{bc}^\intercal: d\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{x}) = \left(\mathbf{c}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{M})\right)\cdot d\mathbf{x},$$
where the final equality is due to $d\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{M}\cdot d\mathbf{x}$.  The result then follows since $ df(\mathbf{x}) = \nabla f(\mathbf{x})\cdot d\mathbf{x}$.